# Removing namespace from SOAP request in XQ

Tags: java, soap, xquery, osb

I am using Oracle service bus to handle REST based services. I need to handle REST to POST conversion in OSB. Bcse ma back-end is a SOAP system. This is a request generated from OSB

```
<soapenv:Body  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
  <get:InputParameters  xmlns:get="http://www.crm.org/CustomerService/"> 
    <get:P_USERNAME>DBAKER</get:P_USERNAME> 
  </get:InputParameters> 
</soapenv:Body>
```

But i need to remove "xmlns:get="http://www.crm.org/CustomerService/"" from my request. bcse it will through an error. I am using OSB Eclipse and Xquery to build requet. Is it possible to handle in XQ.

Comment: Why will a namespace throw an error until and unless you are doing it wrong? I am not clear about the requirement. Can you please post the output xml as well that you are hoping to get after the transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the FunctX function module, especially the change element ns deep function.

http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_change-element-ns-deep.html

Comment: I have tried the same. but my only need  is to remove  "xmlns:get="http://www.crm.org/CustomerService/" from my request.